# C# reflection use variable as object.[var]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, system.reflection

I'm trying to generate a table in a razor view using reflection to pull the properties from the model.

Here is what I've tried:

```
@if (@Model.Count() > 0)
{
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] properties = Model.First().GetType().GetProperties();
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>

            @foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                if (char.IsLower(property.Name.ToCharArray()[0])) //ignore foreign keys
                {
                    continue;
                }
                <th>@property.Name</th>
            }
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (PCNWeb.Models.Switch item in Model)
            {
                /*System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[]*/ properties = item.GetType().GetProperties();
                <tr>
                @foreach (var property in properties)
                {                    
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.[property.Name])
                    </td>
                }
                </tr>

            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

Let me point out the part of the code that I'm not sure what to do with:

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.[property.Name])
</td>
```

The `property.Name` contains the name of the property of item that I want to access.
If I were to hand write the innermost `td` one example would be:

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Switch_Location)
</td>
```

where `"Switch_Location"` is the value of `property.Name`

So basically I need to access the value of a property of item based on the name of the property stored in a variable.

---

EDIT adding model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace PCNWeb.Models
{
    public partial class Switch
    {
        public Switch()
        {
            this.Ports = new List<Port>();
            this.Switch_Location = new Switch_Location();
            this.Switch_Model = new Switch_Model();
            this.UPS = new UPS();
        }
        [Key]
        public int switchRecId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int locationRecId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int modelRecId { get; set; }
        //public int gatewayRecId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int upsRecId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Number { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(64)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [StringLength(80)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [StringLength(32)]
        public string Cabinet { get; set; }

        [StringLength(40)]
        public string Power_Feed { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Nullable<int> ipOctet1 { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Nullable<int> ipOctet2 { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Nullable<int> ipOctet3 { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Nullable<int> ipOctet4 { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Port> Ports { get; set; }
        public virtual Switch_Location Switch_Location { get; set; }
        public virtual Switch_Model Switch_Model { get; set; }
        public virtual UPS UPS { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: might i suggest using a view model?

Comment: @DanielA.White What dose using a ViewModel get me? I really like the idea of having the least amount of handwritten code thus this approach.

Comment: separation of concerns. your code looses maintainability.

Comment: Reflection is **the** most inefficient way to write code. Use it little and not very often!

Comment: I must not understand "separation of concerns" I feel like this method completely decouples the view from the data. And loose coupling is good, so If I change my data I don't have to change my views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So basically I need to access the value of a property of item based on the name of the property stored in a variable.

No, you need to access the value of a property based on a `PropertyInfo` object describing it.  That's far far easier.

```
property.GetValue(item)
```

Comment: using property.GetValue(item) yields this: ```PCNWeb.Models.Switch_Location``` in my datatable. Is there a way to get the actual data?

Comment: That should give the actual data.

Comment: @TechplexEngineer: I think your `Html.DisplayFor` is calling `ToString()` on the object.  If you want to change the string, write a better `Switch_Location.ToString()`

Comment: Ohhhh So I've added my model of a switch above, since a switch has "sub"objects I'll need a way to get their value.

Comment: @BenVoigt `DisplayFor` is more complex than that. It also checks for attributes on the member as hint on how to display the property.

Comment: @BenVoigt It does seem to be calling the ToString() on the columns that aren't outputting their data. I added a ToString() override to the models which returned the datamember that I want to see output but they all are coming back as empty string.

Comment: @TechplexEngineer I figured out that I had stuff like this ```this.Switch_Location = new Switch_Location();``` in the switch model constructor which was emptying all the values.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont really need the DisplayFor method, you can do it like this in your loop:

```
<tbody>
            @foreach (PCNWeb.Models.Switch item in Model)
            {
                /*System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[]*/ properties = item.GetType().GetProperties();
                <tr>
                @foreach (var property in properties)
                {                    
                    <td>
                        @property.GetValue(item,null)
                    </td>
                }
                </tr>

            }
        </tbody>
```

Comment: In the table, this is just printing the propertyName, I was trying to use the DisplayFor to get the propertyValue. How can I access the underlying data?